# MSDeploy to WMSvc ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED using user in Administrators group

Tags: iis-7.5, msdeploy

I've setup a special user account for MSDeploy connections. The user is a member of the local Administrators group.

MSDeploy fails with `ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED` when I use this account and yet it works fine with my own account, which is also an administrator, via a domain group.

In the IIS Management settings, this new website is not listed and so my account doesn't receive its rights via config, I believe its implicit via my admin rights. So why doesn't the dedicated account work?

What I'm learning, from day after day and $1000s worth of consultancy time, is that MSDeploy is another Microsoft over-complicated anti-pattern, we should stick to RoboCopy and not cave in to 'right way' BS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked event log for MsDeploy? It could contain possible answer :).
I assume you are using Windows 2008 Server, not Windows 2012 Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying explicitly the `authType=Basic` token for the `-dest` parameter (or `/A:Basic` command line switch in case of `.cmd` deploy script). Though the documentation claims that WMSvc method uses by default basic authentication I've recently found this is not (always) true.